# PHP rebuild a big array

Tags: php, arrays

```
array (size=10)
  'image' => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => string 'BlackLingerie(42).jpg' (length=21)
      1 => string 'BlackLingerie(43).jpg' (length=21)
      2 => string 'BlackLingerie(44).jpg' (length=21)
  'text' => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => string '' (length=0)
      1 => string '' (length=0)
      2 => string '' (length=0)
  'author' => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => string '' (length=0)
      1 => string '' (length=0)
      2 => string '' (length=0)
  'date' => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => string '' (length=0)
      1 => string '' (length=0)
      2 => string '' (length=0)
  'verImage' => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => string 'upload' (length=6)
      1 => string 'upload' (length=6)
      2 => string 'upload' (length=6)
  'imagePicsPath' => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => string 'http://127.0.0.1/develop/mvc/public/images/pics/BlackLingerie(42).jpg'/' (length=77)
      1 => string 'http://127.0.0.1/develop/mvc/public/images/pics/BlackLingerie(43).jpg'/' (length=77)
      2 => string 'http://127.0.0.1/develop/mvc/public/images/pics/BlackLingerie(44).jpg'/' (length=77)
  'imageThumbPath' => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => string 'http://127.0.0.1/develop/mvc/public/images/thumbs/BlackLingerie(42).jpg'/' (length=79)
      1 => string 'http://127.0.0.1/develop/mvc/public/images/thumbs/BlackLingerie(43).jpg'/' (length=79)
      2 => string 'http://127.0.0.1/develop/mvc/public/images/thumbs/BlackLingerie(44).jpg'/' (length=79)
  'imagePath' => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => string 'http://127.0.0.1/develop/mvc/public/images/pics/BlackLingerie(42).jpg'/' (length=77)
      1 => string 'http://127.0.0.1/develop/mvc/public/images/pics/BlackLingerie(43).jpg'/' (length=77)
      2 => string 'http://127.0.0.1/develop/mvc/public/images/pics/BlackLingerie(44).jpg'/' (length=77)
  'imageID' => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => string '0' (length=1)
      1 => string '1' (length=1)
      2 => string '2' (length=1)
  'submitUploadImages' => string 'Ladda upp bilder till databas' (length=29)
```

Want to rebuild this array to an more useful array. Like this

```
array
   ( [image0] (
       'name' => 
       'text' => 
       'author' => 
       'date' => 
       'verImage' => 
       'imagePicsPath' => 
       'imageThumbPath' => 
       'imagePath' => 
       'imageID' => 
      )
      [image1] (
       'name' => 
       'text' => 
       'author' => 
       'date' => 
       'verImage' => 
       'imagePicsPath' => 
       'imageThumbPath' => 
       'imagePath' => 
       'imageID' => 
      )
```

And so on depending on how many pictures there is, the keys inside the image array holds the values for each image. Like name, path so on. The incoming array is a $_POST that holds multiple form input data. Need some help to crack this one guys. Need to iterate trough the $_POST array, get the contents and transform to a new array ?

I want unique image arrays that holds the image information before doing my stuff with the database =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't tested this but it should work:

```
$incomingArray = $_POST['array'];
$sortedArray = array();

for($i = 0; $i < count($incomingArray); $i++){
    foreach($incomingArray as $key => $value){
        $sortedArray["image".$i][$key] = $value[i];
    }
}
```

Doing it this way means you don't have to write `$sortedArray["image".$i]['NAME'] = $incomingArray['NAME'][$i]` for each image value (name, test, author etc.).

Comment: for($i = 0; $i < count($incomingArray['imageID']); $i++){
    foreach ($incomingArray as $key => $value) {
     $sortedArray["image".$i][$key] = $value[$i];
    }
   }
   var_dump($sortedArray);

Comment: This solved my problem ! Thanks. Some spelling errors in your example but okej =)

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
foreach( $array as $1st_level_key => $1st_level_value ) {
    foreach ( $1st_level_value as $2nd_level_key => $2nd_level_value ) {
        $new_array['image'.$2nd_level_key][$1st_level_key] = $2nd_level_value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Short answer yes, pretty much like this:

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($YourArray); $i++)
{
    $NewArray["image".$i]["name"] = $YourArray["name"][$i];
    ...
}
```